# DataGridViewRow index out of range exception on refresh

Tags: c#, datagridview, refresh, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a data grid view in my C# application. When I highlight the line and I hit delete, the row will delete but when I run the update and refresh command I am getting an index out of range exception

```
private void btnDeleteMember_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dgvAllFaculty.SelectedRows)
    {
        int row = item.Index;
        FacultyMember member = memberList[row];

        if (row >= 0)
        {
            memberList.RemoveAt(row);

            Save();
            this.dgvAllFaculty.Update();
            this.dgvAllFaculty.Refresh();
            return;
        }

     }
}
```

While debugging I notice it fails on the refresh call.The error I get is

```
System.IndexOutOfRangException: Index 1 does not have a value
  at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
  at
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32 rowIndex)
```

If there something else you need to see let me know. I am wondering if when the refresh is happening its mad cause it still thinks the second row is there?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I changed my code around a little bit and its now working. I had to reload the data from the json file first before refreshing.

```
private void btnDeleteMember_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = this.dgvAllFaculty.SelectedRows.Count;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dgvAllFaculty.SelectedRows)
        {
            int i = item.Index;
            FacultyMember member = memberList[i];
            memberList.RemoveAt(i);
            Save();
        }

        if (count > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} faculty memebers deleted", count));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Faculty Member Deleted");
        }

        // Load the newest data from file before refreshing the view
        ViewAll_Load(sender, e);
        this.Refresh();
    }
```